# Resave a models into a try catch

Tags: django, django-models

this is a design question.

Suppose an Organisation with a name and a code

```
class Organisation(models.Model):
    """
    Class to manage Organisations.
    """
    name = models.CharField(_('Name'), max_length=50)
    code = models.CharField(_('Code'),
            max_length=8,
            editable=False,
            unique=True)
```

To avoid code problems, i use this save method:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    """ override save method to add specific values """
    if self.pk is None:
        self.code = strftime('%y%m')+str(uuid4())[:4]
    try:
        super(Organisation, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    except IntegrityError:
        self.code = strftime('%y%m')+str(uuid4())[:4]
        super(Organisation, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

As you can imagine, this code doesn't works, it's a bad code but i don't know how to do :'(
EDIT: code format is a constraint, i cannot change it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I undestand it you are getting an `IntegrityError` because your `code` has to be unique.
You could filter in the `save` method if an instance with the same code already exists:

```
def _generate_code(self):
    # have the whole code generation in one place
    return strftime('%y%m')+str(uuid4())[:4]

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.pk is None:
        self.code = self._generate_code()
        while Organisation.objects.filter(code=self.code).exists():
            self.code = self._generate_code()
    super(Organisation, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Maybe there are better ways to generate your code but don't know why it must be a piece of a uuid4. You could also try a random string with the character set you need.

Comment: he he this is exactly what i did since i've posted this question :) My main problem is i hate using while boucles because we don't have controle on so i've scared with infinite boucles. I guess i've no choices here, thanks for your concrete answer :)

Comment: If you want a unique time based ID you could also look at `uuid1`

Comment: You can avoid an infinite while loop with a large for loop

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a unique suffix then you can check if it exists and keep trying till you generate a non-existent code.

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    """ override save method to add specific values """
    if self.pk is None:
        for i in range(100):    # Try 100 times to avoid infinite loops 
            code = strftime('%y%m')+str(uuid4())[:4]
            if not Organisation.objects.filter(code=code):
                 break
        self.code = code
    super(Organisation, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```